# Maximum of an array at indices provided in another array in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given an array `a = [0.51, 0.6, 0.8, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9]` and an indices array `ind = [0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]`. Find the maximum value for each value in index and replace that in the corresponding place in the array a. So here the output should be `out = [0.51, 0.65, 0.9, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75, 0.9]`.

Explanation: Consider value 1 in the `ind` array. The values at the corresponding positions are `[0.6, 0.65]`. The maximum value is 0.65. Replace that at corresponding positions (1 and 3) in array a.

Interested in the vectorized code. The code using for loop is pretty simple.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.51, 0.6, 0.8, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9])
ind = np.array([0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3])

# Get unique indices
unique_indices = np.unique(ind)

# Loop through unique indices and find max value for each index
for index in unique_indices:
    max_value = np.max(a[ind == index])
    a[ind == index] = max_value

out = a
print(out)
```

What I have explored: I think we can use `np.naximum.reduceat` here but still not sure how to create a working code using it.

Comment: numpy doesn't provide a good groupby operation. If you're open to other package, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can do it like this: `pd.Series(a).groupby(ind).transform('max')`

Comment: I am actually looking for PyTorch code but I suspected that will be even more difficult.

Comment: `m = np.zeros(ind.max()+1); np.maximum.at(m, ind, a); m[ind]`, `pytorch` doesn't provide a `at` ufunc. [`pytorch-scatter`](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter) package implements `scatter_max`, but `pip install torch-scatter`seems to be broken.

Comment: If `np.maximum.at` is not enough, you can use Numba which can provide faster performance in this case (because Numpy use generic ufunc calls internally).